# jQuery slideToggle jump animation on menu toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, drop-down-menu, menu

So my problem is just as simple as the title, when I click the big black "V" to toggle my menu, the animation jumps on the `<li>` with the sub menu.

I tried multiple things and none seem to work, I had a similar issue with the `width` which I solved by setting `width` to 100%. On my search I saw people that jQuery can't figure out the height of the elements but if I try to add height to the elements it totaly breaks the menu.

Here's the codepen so you can experience my problem. [CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/andreforte/pen/MyYZMR)

HTML

```
    <nav class="main-menu">
   <ul>
      <li class="level-1"><a href="<?php echo get_category_link( 5 ) ?>">Item 1</a>
         <span class="toggle-1">V</span>
         <ul class="sub-menu-1">
            <li class="level-2"><a href="<?php echo get_category_link( 9 ) ?>">Item 1.1</a>
               <span class="toggle-2">V</span>
               <ul class="sub-menu-2">
                  <li class="level-3"><a href="<?php echo get_category_link( 11 ) ?>">Item 1.1.1</a></li>
                  <li class="level-3"><a href="<?php echo get_category_link( 12 ) ?>">Item 1.1.2</a></li>
                  <li class="level-3"><a href="<?php echo get_category_link( 13 ) ?>">Item 1.1.3</a></li>
                  <li class="level-3"><a href="<?php echo get_category_link( 14 ) ?>">Item 1.1.4</a></li>
               </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="level-2"><a href="<?php echo get_category_link( 10 ) ?>">Item 1.2</a>
               <span class="toggle-2">V</span>
               <ul class="sub-menu-2">
                  <li class="level-3"><a href="<?php echo get_category_link( 15 ) ?>">Item 1.2.1</a></li>
                  <li class="level-3"><a href="<?php echo get_category_link( 16 ) ?>">Item 1.2.2</a></li>
               </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="level-2"><a href="<?php echo get_category_link( 25 ) ?>">Item 1.3</a></li>
         </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="level-1"><a href="<?php echo get_category_link( 6 ) ?>">Item 2</a>
         <span class="toggle-1">V</span>
         <ul class="sub-menu-1">
            <li class="level-2"><a href="<?php echo get_category_link( 18 ) ?>">Item 2.1</a></li>
            <li class="level-2"><a href="<?php echo get_category_link( 19 ) ?>">Item 2.2</a></li>
            <li class="level-2"><a href="<?php echo get_category_link( 20 ) ?>">Item 2.3</a></li>
            <li class="level-2"><a href="<?php echo get_category_link( 21 ) ?>">Item 2.4</a></li>
            <li class="level-2"><a href="<?php echo get_category_link( 22 ) ?>">Item 2.5</a></li>
         </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="level-1"><a href="<?php echo get_category_link( 7 ) ?>">Item 3</a></li>
      <li class="level-1"><a href="<?php echo get_category_link( 8 ) ?>">BItem 4</a>
         <span class="toggle-1">V</span>
         <ul class="sub-menu-1">
            <li class="level-2"><a href="<?php echo get_category_link( 23 ) ?>">Item 4.1</a></li>
            <li class="level-2"><a href="<?php echo get_category_link( 24 ) ?>">Item 4.2</a></li>
         </ul>
      </li>
   </ul>
</nav>
```

CSS

```
.main-menu .sub-menu-1, .main-menu .sub-menu-2 {
    display: none;
}
.main-menu ul {
    width: 100%;
}
.main-menu li {
    line-height: 25px;
}
.main-menu li.level-1 {
    background-color: red;
}
.main-menu li.level-2 {
    background-color: lightblue;
}
.main-menu li.level-3 {
    background-color: yellow;
}
.main-menu a {
    display: block;
    margin-right: 20px;
}
.main-menu .toggle-1, .main-menu .toggle-2 {
    display: block;
    float: right;;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    width: 20px;
    transform: translateY(-25px);
}
```

Javascript/jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {

      $('.sub-menu-1, .sub-menu-2').hide();
      $('.toggle-1').click( function() {
         $(this).next('.sub-menu-1').slideToggle();
      });

      $('.toggle-2').click( function() {
         $(this).next('.sub-menu-2').slideToggle();
      });

   });
```

Thank you in advance and hope somenone can help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is arising from the `<span>` that you have set to `display: block;` in your css.

Switching `.main-menu a` and `.main-menu .toggle-1, .main-menu .toggle-2` to both be `display: inline-block;` fixes the issue. You can then also remove some additional unnecessary css hacks that you were previously using to forcibly place these elements outside of their document flow position.

The updated CSS is below, and you can see a fork of the pen with both sub-menus working [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WwbmQv)

```
.main-menu a {
  display: inline-block;
}
.main-menu .toggle-1, .main-menu .toggle-2 {
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Thank for your answer, the hacks was because of the width problem I had before but with this solution its nice and clean.

Answer (score 0):

I think the only problem is that you didn't set the `clear` property to your float. If you set it like:

```
.main-menu a {
    margin-right: 20px;
}
.main-menu .toggle-1, .main-menu .toggle-2 {
    float: right;
    clear: none;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    width: 20px;
}
```

you are good. Then you also don't need the `transform: translate` to shift your elements back. Here's a fork of your codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WwbPLV

Comment: Thank you for your anwser, it was useful.